# Examples to show how useful or not useful of dimerization, trimerization, tetramerization and their likes in synthesizing alkenes and other compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, heterocyclic-compounds

this answer shows that [dimerization is a synthetic method](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/34009/101483)
On wikipedia, [1-octene is showed to made from numerous dimerizations or a tetramerization.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Octene)

When I read that [piperazine  $\ce{C4H10N2}$ is made with ammoniation of chloroethanes or alkanolamines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piperazine#Industrial_production), I wonder if *few repeating units synthesis* is a general trend for making polyenes and heterocyclic saturated compounds. If dreaming is allowed, could dimerizing ethylamine $\ce{C2H7N}$ with eliminating hydrogen or aziridine $\ce{C2H5N}$ make piperazine?

For the title, I am hesitant to use telomerization or oligomerization because I am unsure about them in the contexts of this question.

Comment: It is not so simple. You may of course add or subtract atoms as you want. But this approach is not sufficient. It is much more important to take care of the way the atoms are present in space and react. This is not as easy as counting  atoms.

Comment: You can't judge whether such reactions will happen by looking at the composition of the potential monomers. You need to have realistic *mechanism* to make the oligomerization happen.